# Visual Studio suddenly stopped accessing database after changing connection string

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, connection-string

I had a running system on Visual Studio 2008 and it always managed to access the database successfully. I am using SQL Express 2005

I had this string:

```
Driver={SQL Server}; Server = MyName-PC ; Database=RBMonDB; Uid=; Pwd=;
```

But the server on connection string is stuck on one PC. So I tried to make a generic string and did this.

```
Driver={SQL Server}; Server = . ; Database=RBMonDB; Uid=; Pwd=;
```

I replaced the original Server name with a " . "

It run normally for the first time. But after trying to run it the second time around I get this:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied
```

What happened? I am really clueless about this. I still a newbie so please understand. Thank you

Comment: I would have expected something like `Driver={SQL Server}; Server = .\SQLExpress ; Database=RBMonDB; Uid=; Pwd=;` or perhaps `Driver={SQL Server}; Server = localhost; Database=RBMonDB; Uid=; Pwd=;`

Comment: +1 paul. 
"." is a shortcut for "default sql server instance" on "localhost". With SqlExpress the default instance name is "\SQLExpress". But you should be aware that even doing that limits you to having the database on the same machine as the application.

Comment: .\SQLEXPRESS but I get an error that says it cannot access the database. I also tried localhost but it did not work.